# Не загружаюься фото на сервер

Tags: php

```
                 <?php move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/mollir.kl.com.ua/Mollir/photos/". $_FILES["file"]["name"]); ?>
```

Почему фото не загружаются в директорию? Я даже проверил настройки php и пункт file_uploads имеет значение on

Comment: У Вашей формы атрибут encrypt стоит? Вы пробовали вывести массив $_FILES через print_r?

Comment: Атрибут encrypt  стоит, нет не пробовал, но попробую .

Comment: Уже попробовал, все как надо. Ошибок нет

Comment: Опишите полностью форму, которой Вы пытаетесь загрузить файл, и на всякий случай вывод `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: Ваш путь начинается со слеша, это значит что путь ищется от корня файловой системы. 146% этого пути __не существует__

Comment: html форму? Вот массив $_FILES Array ( [photo] => Array ( [name] => Lighthouse.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpW8DwVU [error] => 0 [size] => 561276 ) )

Comment: А почему не существует?